# Change the "New" button Quote subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

The opportunity form as a quotes sub-grid. I am trying to hide the existing "New" button and create a custom one.  Hiding the existing button works like a charm. However, nothing I do seems to make the custom button appear.

I have tried making the enable and visibility conditions as simple as just checking that the form is for an existing entity.  Nothing seems to work.

Here's the XML for the quote.  Generated using Ribbon Workbench:

```
<RibbonDiffXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.quote.MainTab.Management.Controls._children" Sequence="17">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Alt="$LocLabels:ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.Alt" Command="ntcp.quote.Command0.Command" Description="" Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/newrecord32.png" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/New_16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.LabelText" Sequence="17" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription" ModernImage="New" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
    <HideCustomAction HideActionId="ntcp.Mscrm.SubGrid.quote.AddNewStandard.Hide" Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.quote.AddNewStandard" />
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates" />
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="ntcp.quote.Command0.Command">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="ntcp.quote.EnableRule0.EnableRule" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="ntcp.quote.DisplayRule0.DisplayRule" />
      </DisplayRules>
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="ntcp_QuoteFromOpportunity" Library="$webresource:ntcp_/quoteFromOpportunity.js" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="ntcp.quote.DisplayRule0.DisplayRule">
        <FormStateRule State="Existing" Default="true" />
      </DisplayRule>
    </DisplayRules>
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="ntcp.quote.EnableRule0.EnableRule">
        <FormStateRule State="Existing" Default="true" />
      </EnableRule>
    </EnableRules>
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels>
    <LocLabel Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Add New Quote" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Add New Quote" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Add New Quote" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="ntcp.quote.Button1.Button.Alt">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Add New Quote" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
  </LocLabels>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this CRM2011 or CRM2013? If it is CRM2013 you can't add a new button on the Form Subgrids - only on the full related subgrid view.

Buttons are visible by default, so you don't need any special Display/Enable rules.

Hope this helps,
Scott

Comment: [You cannot customise this mini Sub Grid at this time other than overriding the 'Add' and 'Delete' command - you cannot add buttons or change the icons of buttons on the mini Sub Grid, but full customisation is supported on the full Sub Grid Command Bar.](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/4-things-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-Command-Bar.aspx)

Comment: My blog post on this area might help - http://develop1.net/public/post/4-things-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-Command-Bar.aspx